# Set a common header for certain components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I'm developing a reactjs app and there are several components in the app. For example initially the login page is displayed and when logged in it will navigate to home component. So in home component i need to have a common header menu for each page inside the home component. What is the best approach to do this? 
Do i create a HeaderMenu component and import it to each and every other component inside home or is there a way to just import it once for the components inside home ?

For example

Component A

```
 <div className="body_clr">

        <NavigationTop
          componentURL={this.props.location.pathname}
          reqUserId={reqUserId}
        />

        <Home/>


</div>
```

Component B

```
<div className="body_clr">

        <NavigationTop
          componentURL={this.props.location.pathname}
          reqUserId={reqUserId}
        />

        <UserManagement/>


</div>
```

Here `NavigationTop` is my header menu and i have imported it to all the components that i need this and not included it where i do need this (Ex: Initial login page).

Is this the correct approach ?

Comment: You said it right my friend: "i need to have a common header menu for each page inside the home"; if it's common and it should be placed in the same location for every section, then importing it once makes the most sense. You are on the right track.

Comment: You can dynamically render the header component if the user is logined in the app.js once,  no need to put the header to all other components.